# python-telegram-bot.I already PORT 8443 but Error while bootstrap set webhook: Bad webhook: webhook can be set up only on ports 80, 88, 443 or 8443

Tags: python, linux, heroku, python-telegram-bot

I just find the post without any reply on stackoverflow when i create this post...
[TelegramBot. "Webhook can be set up only on ports 80, 88, 443 or 8443" error on heroku webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533321/telegrambot-webhook-can-be-set-up-only-on-ports-80-88-443-or-8443-error-on)

my testing code is here:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import logging

import os
    
import telegram
from flask import Flask, request
from telegram.ext import  Updater, Dispatcher, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler

env = ConfigParser()
env.read('config.ini')
TOKEN = env['TELEGRAM']['ACCESS_TOKEN']

PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))

updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)


#
#body part ( that's not important to show)
#


updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                      port=PORT,
                      url_path=TOKEN)
updater.bot.set_webhook("https://tgbot00.herokuapp.com/" + TOKEN)
updater.idle()
```

but server told me ...

```
here2021-03-19T14:48:06.712894+00:00 app[web.1]: Error while bootstrap set webhook: Bad webhook: webhook can be set up only on ports 80, 88, 443 or 8443

2021-03-19T14:48:06.713033+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed bootstrap phase after 0 retries (Bad webhook: webhook can be set up only on ports 80, 88, 443 or 8443)
```

I have struggled these about a week and almost success
but somehow so less information found on google

Do I need to setup something on my remoted Linux system about PORT.?

could someone help .?

thx a lot...!

UPDATE----------------------------------------
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku

I think this is not about SSL problem

```
Heroku
On Heroku using webhook can be beneficial on the free-plan because it will
automatically manage the downtime required. The reverse proxy is set up for you and an environment 
is created. From this environment you will have to extract the port the bot is supposed to listen on. 
Heroku manages the SSL on the proxy side, so you don't have provide the certificate yourself.
```

Comment: Looks all fine, how did you define the webhook url? Maybe check that the URL starts with HTTPS

Comment: um... i am sorry , what do you mean of "the webhook url" ..?
btw  . thank you so much your attention

Comment: yes, you call the Telegram setWebook URL to define the url of your service

Comment: ops  you mean  api.telegram.org/bot{}/setWebhook?url={}

..... i just set url to "https://{appname}.herokuapp.com/"  that shows on heroku setting - domain

Comment: it looks all good, really weird. It seems that your Heroku app doesnt run on SSL which should not be the case as (like you pointed out) the SSL is provided by the platform and you dont need to do anything

Comment: Something to try is to print out the value of PORT, to make sure it does get the value provided by Heroku

Comment: So , i do as you told..
There is no any number show is 80, 88, 443 or 8443 
So.., what's the next step..?

Comment: Have no idea the next step i should do .
Is there more information complete detail information online .?

Comment: btw  thanks your advice even this is not a big helpful... lol

Comment: Try to get the PORT from within the method that call bot.setWebhook. Everything else looks like my repo where I deploy to Heroku without problems, feel free to have a look https://github.com/gcatanese/TelegramBotDemo

Comment: I just try using polling  without using <logging> < Flask> with another code to test ....just Updater(token= {})  and it all works smooth.... I just have a look of your link example  . its pretty cool !!  thx a lot = D

Answer (score 11):

Documentation updated: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku

```
import os
TOKEN = "TOKEN"
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
# add handlers
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                      port=PORT,
                      url_path=TOKEN,
                      webhook_url="https://<appname>.herokuapp.com/" + TOKEN)
updater.idle()
```

Not use `set_webhook` , use `webhook_url` param in `start_webhook`

Comment: thank you, it solved my issue